# own component... functions wont work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, components, cocos2d-iphone

I tried to create a own GUI component with cocos 2d.  I have written a class (extends Sprite).  This class initialize with graphics and a label.  If I create an instance of my class I can see my component but I can't use any functions.  I wrote a `setLabel` function but the label change.

I created an instance with this code:

```
drop1 = [DropDown init];

//here I call the function but it dont works :-(
[drop1 setCaption:@"Produkt"];

///dropDown.m:

#import "DropDown.h"

@implementation DropDown

@synthesize captionLbl;
+ (id) init
{
if( (self=[super init] ))
{
return [[[self spriteWithFile:@"menue_dropdownbtn.png"] addChild:[[self alloc] initActiveState]] addChild:[[self alloc] initLabel]];
}
}

- (id)initActiveState
{
activated = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"menue_dropactiveated.png"];
[activated setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];
[activated setPosition:ccp(173,0)];
[activated setVisible:NO];
return activated;
}

- (id)initLabel
{
captionLbl = [Label labelWithString:@"Text" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:14.0f];
[captionLbl setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];
[captionLbl setPosition:ccp(10,5)];
[captionLbl setRGB:0 :0 :0];
return captionLbl;
}

- (void)setCaption:(NSString*)text
{
[captionLbl setString:text];
NSLog(@"Hallooooo");
}

- (void)activate
{
[activated setVisible:YES];
isActive = YES;
}

- (void)deactivate
{
[activated setVisible:NO];
isActive = NO;
}

@end

// DropDown.h
//

//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface DropDown : Sprite
{
BOOL isActive;

@private
Sprite* activated;
Label* captionLbl;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Label* captionLbl;

+ (id) init;
- (id)initActiveState;
- (id)initLabel;
- (void)setCaption:(NSString*)text;
- (void)activate;
- (void)deactivate;
@end
```

---

I can't remove the `alloc` because it is needed to access the instance functions.

Here is the original cocos2d `Sprite` class:

```
@interface Sprite (Private)
// lazy allocation
-(void) initAnimationDictionary;
@end

@implementation Sprite

#pragma mark Sprite - image file
+ (id) spriteWithFile:(NSString*) filename
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithFile:filename] autorelease];
}

- (id) initWithFile:(NSString*) filename
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self ) {
        // texture is retained
        self.texture = [[TextureMgr sharedTextureMgr] addImage: filename];

        // lazy alloc
        animations = nil;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark Sprite - CGImageRef

+ (id) spriteWithCGImage: (CGImageRef) image
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithCGImage:image] autorelease];
}

- (id) initWithCGImage: (CGImageRef) image
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self ) {
        // XXX: possible bug. See issue #349. New API should be added
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08X",(unsigned long)image];
        self.texture = [[TextureMgr sharedTextureMgr] addCGImage:image forKey:key];


        // lazy alloc
        animations = nil;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark Sprite - Texture2D

+ (id)  spriteWithTexture:(Texture2D*) tex
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithTexture:tex] autorelease];
}

- (id) initWithTexture:(Texture2D*) tex
{
    if( (self = [super init]) ) {
        // texture is retained
        self.texture = tex;

        // lazy alloc
        animations = nil;
    }
    return self;
}   

#pragma mark Sprite

-(void) dealloc
{
    [animations release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) initAnimationDictionary
{
    animations = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2] retain];
}

//
// CocosNodeFrames protocol
//
-(void) setDisplayFrame:(id)frame
{
    self.texture = frame;
}

-(void) setDisplayFrame: (NSString*) animationName index:(int) frameIndex
{
    if( ! animations )
        [self initAnimationDictionary];

    Animation *a = [animations objectForKey: animationName];
    Texture2D *frame = [[a frames] objectAtIndex:frameIndex];
    self.texture = frame;   
}

-(BOOL) isFrameDisplayed:(id)frame
{
    return texture_ == frame;
}
-(id) displayFrame
{
    return texture_;
}
-(void) addAnimation: (id<CocosAnimation>) anim
{
    // lazy alloc
    if( ! animations )
        [self initAnimationDictionary];

    [animations setObject:anim forKey:[anim name]];
}
-(id<CocosAnimation>)animationByName: (NSString*) animationName
{
    NSAssert( animationName != nil, @"animationName parameter must be non nil");
    return [animations objectForKey:animationName];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your `init` function in `dropDown.m`. You call `[[self alloc] initActiveState]]` and `[[self alloc] initLabel]]` for the `addChild:` arguments, but what that's actually doing is reallocating space for the entire object. Instead, you should do the allocation in your `initActiveState` and `initLabel` methods. Try changing those to `[ self initActiveState ]` and `[ self initLabel ]` (omitting the `alloc` call) and see where that gets you.

It might help to post the code to your `Sprite` class, as you're using methods that are inherited from it.